# how to fix 'pulling image configuration from docker when i download hyperledgerfabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, download

I'm trying to download Fabric in ubuntu but I couldn't because it shows that error.

```
error pulling image configuration: Get https://production.cloudflare.docker.com/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/c8/c8b4909d8d46f41dc8a111937e4bacf2b3b4cf2816c8553ffde2cf497acd901d/data?verify=1550251944-uHSYU8poIp5GJZPGIQBvWIJ6Pz4%3D: dial tcp: lookup production.cloudflare.docker.com on 127.0.0.53:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:46587->127.0.0.53:53: i/o timeout
```

Answer (score -1):

I/O Timeout indicates that it's just an internet connection issue. I would suggest to change to a faster and/or stable connection and try again.

If it still exists, update your question with required system config.